# Prove that the following determinant is equal to $\sin(2(x+y))$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Prove that
>   $$\left|\begin {array}   c 
> \cos(x+y) & \sin(x+y) & -\cos(x+y)\\ 
> \sin(x-y) & \cos(x-y) & \sin(x-y) \\ 
> \sin{2x} & 0 & \sin (2y)
> \end {array}\right|
> =\sin(2(x+y))$$

It is my question. I have tried several types of operations such as $C_1=C_1 + C_3$ and many others but I failed. Somebody please help me.

Comment: calculate the determinant using [Sarrus' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)  and simplyfy. I didn't try this but I don't expect any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posing $X=x+y$ and $Y=x-y$, the determinant becomes:

$$\Delta=\left|\begin {array}   c 
\cos(X) & \sin(X) & -\cos(X)\\ 
\sin(Y) & \cos(Y) & \sin(Y) \\ 
\sin(X+Y) & 0 & \sin (X-Y)
\end {array}\right|$$

Because of the zero at $(3,2)$, Sarrus's rule yields an expression of the determinant as a sum of four terms (instead of six):

$$\Delta=\cos(X)\cos(Y)\sin(X-Y) + \sin(X)\sin(Y)\sin(X+Y) -\sin(X)\sin(Y)\sin(X-Y)\\+\cos(X)\cos(Y)\sin(X+Y)$$
which, after simplifications, turns out to be $\sin(2X)=\sin(2x+2y)$ because:

\begin{align}\Delta &= \sin(X+Y)\big[\cos(X)\cos(Y)+\sin(X)\sin(Y)\big] \\&\qquad\qquad + \sin(X-Y)\big[\cos(X)\cos(Y) -\sin(X)\sin(Y)\big]\\ &= \sin(X+Y)\cos(X-Y) +\sin(X-Y)\cos(X+Y)\\ &= \sin(2X)
\end{align}

Comment: is there really an advantage in using this substitution? What did you gain?

Comment: Simplicity (it replaces most $\cos(x+y)$ by $\cos(X)$).